# get weird results from SQL query using "%"

Tags: php, sql, database

I tried to get results from my database using SQL but my results do not agree with what i am using as input. I always gets results from those who contains both integers and characters. For example, if i search for "liu" i get a result of "2LK020". I neither cant search with integers and get a correct result... I use:

```
    $result = queryDatabase(
    "SELECT course_tag, course_name FROM course WHERE course_tag OR course_name LIKE ?",
    array(1 => '%' .$parameters[0]. '%')
```

is there a problem using "%"? or why do i get this weird answers?

Comment: `course_tag OR course_name LIKE ?` should be `course_tag = 'something' OR course_name LIKE ?`

Answer (score 4):

Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html

You're doing the equivalent of

```
WHERE course_tag OR (course_name LIKE ?)
```

which comes to

```
WHERE true/false OR true/false
```

As long as `course_tag` isn't an empty string or a null or other "falsey" value, it'll pretty much always evaluate to a `true` value, and make the entire `WHERE` clause evaluate to `true`.

You can't test multiple fields against a single `LIKE` value. That simply doesn't work. You need to test each one individually:

```
WHERE (course_tag LIKE ?) OR (course_name LIKE ?)
```

However, since you're doing a `%...%` double-wild card search, you could optimize a bit with

```
WHERE CONCAT(course_tag, course_name) LIKE ?
```

Comment: Is there any proof this use of CONCAT gives better performance?

Comment: probably equivalent. you're using `%..%` like queries anyways, which makes it impossible to use indexes. either way you're forcing a full table scan. you should probably look into using a fulltext index instead, which can cover both fields.